# JDEV 12.2.1.4 Integrated Weblogic not running

Tags: weblogic12c, jdeveloper

We're using Jdev 12.2.1.4, while starting the integrated wls instance it's throwing below error-
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate file distributions\JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.4.0.xml under lookup locations.
JDK version- jdk 1.8.162

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some JAVA_HOME related issues in .globalEnv.properties  file. Additionally some permission issues were there in  JDeveloper_Integrated_Server_Suite_12.2.1.4.0.xml  file. Pointing to correct java_home and giving my permission to this xml file has resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Oracle-Jdk.I dont think 12.2.1.4 version not supported by Jdk 1.6. Read this documentation:

> https://www.oracle.com/application-development/technologies/jdeveloper/1212-cert.html

Comment: Sorry for the typo-it's 1.8.162